Snowflake to_varchar adds space in front
Anyone can explain why to_varchar function in Snowflake adds space in front of output:
For example,
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(10101, '000000');
-- ouput: ' 010101'
SELECT LEN(TO_VARCHAR(10101, '000000'))
-- ouput: 7

I could wrap it with TRIM, but would like to understand behavior instead of adding unnecessary functions

The format mask 000000 returns a 6 digit left-zero padded string...what is not clear about this, or what is your end goal?

@TimBiegeleisen my goal is 6-character-long zero-padded string". What is unclear why it returns 7 character long string where 1st char is space.

@HumbleHero SELECT TO_VARCHAR(10101, 'FM000000'), LEN(TO_VARCHAR(10101, 'FM000000'));

So rewriting the comments together: This happens due to default behavour to allocate space Sign position for fixed-position formats

By default, fixed-position formats always reserve a space for the number’s sign:

For non-negative numbers, the default blank space is printed before the first digit.

For negative numbers, the default blank space and - sign are printed before the first digit (or decimal, when the B format element is used for fractional numbers).



The solution is to explicitly tell it to not to using Fill Mode
select 
    $1 as a, 
    to_varchar($1,'000000') as b,
    len(b) as len_b,
    TO_VARCHAR($1, 'FM000000') as c, -- Lukasz answer
    len(c) as len_c
from values 
    (-10),
    (10),
    (0),
    (10101);




A
B
LEN_B
C
LEN_C




-10
-000010
7
-000010
7


10
000010
7
000010
6


0
000000
7
000000
6


10101
010101
7
010101
6




The behaviour you're seeing with TO_VARCHAR(10101, '000000') returning ' 010101' (with a leading space) is because Snowflake adds a space by default when the number is positive to leave room for a potential negative sign.

TO_VARCHAR(10101, '000000') formats the number 10101 according to the pattern '000000', which ensures the number is padded with leading zeros to a total length of 6 characters. The result is '010101', but since it's positive, a space is reserved at the front for a potential negative sign. Hence, the result is ' 010101' (with the leading space).

The function LEN(TO_VARCHAR(10101, '000000')) then returns 7 because of this space.


You can refer the snowflake documentation for more information: snowflake documentation example

The documentation you link doesn't directly mention this. This page looks more relevant. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models - also indicates that maybe the OP should use "compact mode" if they don't want this? but I don't have a snowflake instance handy to test this
